# How to gather terms into Elementary Symmetric Polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to gather the terms of this polynomial (and much higher order ones):

$$q = 1-3 c+c^2+p[1]-2 c p[1]+p[2]-2 c p[2]+p[1] p[2]-c p[1] p[2]+p[3]-2 c p[3]+p[1] p[3]-c p[1] p[3]+p[2] p[3]-c p[2] p[3]+p[1] p[2] p[3]+p[4]-2 c p[4]+p[1] p[4]-c p[1] p[4]+p[2] p[4]-c p[2] p[4]+p[1] p[2] p[4]+p[3] p[4]-c p[3] p[4]+p[1] p[3] p[4]+p[2] p[3] p[4]+p[1] p[2] p[3] p[4]+p[5]-2 c p[5]+p[1] p[5]-c p[1] p[5]+p[2] p[5]-c p[2] p[5]+p[1] p[2] p[5]+p[3] p[5]-c p[3] p[5]+p[1] p[3] p[5]+p[2] p[3] p[5]+p[1] p[2] p[3] p[5]+p[4] p[5]-c p[4] p[5]+p[1] p[4] p[5]+p[2] p[4] p[5]+p[1] p[2] p[4] p[5]+p[3] p[4] p[5]+p[1] p[3] p[4] p[5]+p[2] p[3] p[4] p[5]$$

Into a much more convenient form like this:

$$q = 1 - 3c+c^2+(1-2c)e[1] + e[2] + e[3] + e[4]$$

Where the e[]'s are the [Elementary Symmetric Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of the p[]'s.  How might I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SymmetricReduction[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricReduction.html) for this. In particular, if you want the elementary symmetric polynomials to be represented symbolically instead of explicitly, you can use the three-argument form like so:

```
SymmetricReduction[q, Array[p, 5], Array[e, 5]] // Total
   1 - 3 c + c^2 + (1 - 2 c) e[1] + (1 - c) e[2] + e[3] + e[4]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.